# Find matching row in one table based on the value from second

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to figure out way to find a row based on the value from other table. Suppose I have a local table which stores Rating values and corresponding letter grades from S&P and Moody's:

```
row_id  Moody's S&P Moody's Rating Factor
1   A1  A+  70
2   A2  A   120
3   A3  A-  180
4   Aa1 AA+ 10
5   Aa2 AA  20
6   Aa3 AA- 40
7   Aaa AAA 1
8   B1  B+  2220
9   B2  B   2720
10  B3  B-  3490
11  Ba1 BB+ 940
12  Ba2 BB  1350
13  Ba3 BB- 1766
14  Baa1    BBB+    260
15  Baa2    BBB 360
16  Baa3    BBB-    610
17  C   D   10000
18  Ca  C   10000
19  Ca  CC  10000
20  Caa1    CCC+    4770
21  Caa2    CCC 6500
22  Caa3    CCC-    8070
23  NR  NR  10000
```

My second table stores Rating values for several products, e.g.

```
item    value
12345   2113.48869296578
```

And the rule here is: 2113 is between 2220 and 1766, so I should take the lower grade which is BB- which is in 13th row.

Comment: A Dlookup() will return the first value it finds in a table or query, so create a query that sorts by your rating factor and use a Dlookup on that query.

Comment: It actually returns a value, but this always comes from first row, regardless whether the Ratings table is sorted or nor.

Comment: Are you using RatingFactor >= TestValue as the criteria for the DLookup ?

Comment: Here is what I did: Expr: DLookUp("[Moody's Rating Factor]","aux_CONVERTION_TABLE_SORTED","[Moody's Rating Factor]">="[value]") I am getting blank records in output.

Comment: You really need to make sensible field names, that's a nightmare... I wouldn't use a Dlookup in a query, but try `Expr: DLookUp("[Moody's Rating Factor]","aux_CONVERTION_TABLE_SORTED","[Moody's Rating Factor] > = " & [value])`

Comment: Is there any way to perform an update query based on DLookUp()? Really, the reason why I'm doing this is to update just one field in the database table.. I've already tried several subqueries based on the absolute difference between these two values but it always brings me to the higher grade.

Comment: Yes, can use the result of domain aggregate in UPDATE sql. But if you can get SELECT query to return correct value why bother with UPDATE? You might actually need DMin or DMax in this situation.